# Excel 365 wants to add an at sign @ which is breaking my formula. How do I fix this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have a formula I've been using to analyze data for a few years. My company recently implemented some changes which causes Excel to add an 'at sign' before the arrays. That formula won't return anything, but the old one returns the expected data. The goal in this case is to add data from the matching row in the Analysis sheet to the current sheet. There is a 1:1 match for each row. I can't share the sheets due to the information they contain.

This formula works, but Excel has a pop up saying it's no longer supported:
`=INDEX(Analysis!$E$1:$E$600,MATCH(1, (C163=Analysis!$A$1:$A$600) * (D163=Analysis!$B$1:$B$600) * (I163=Analysis!$C$1:$C$600), 0))`

This is the new Excel version that returns NO data.
`INDEX(Analysis!$E$1:$E$600,MATCH(1, (C162=@Analysis!$A$1:$A$600) * (D162=@Analysis!$B$1:$B$600) * (I162=@Analysis!$A$2:$C$600), 0))`

The posts I can find about it from MS says this change shouldn't impact anything but I have seen a few comments that it can break things from others. Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working and how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just use FILTER?

Comment: It was an array formula, and now you are trying to enter it as a normal formula?